# Stuck at refreshing gradle project. What is happening under the hood?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I can not build any android project in Android Studio. Recently Android studio was updated to 2.3 as well as the gradle version. I think somewhere the update has messed up I am not sure where it is. I have deleted `.gradle` directory from the `home` folder several times by now. Changed the `distributionUrl` to older version of gradle. But the problem persists. Where to look at what is going on? How to solve this issue?

Comment: Please try this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41116687/gradle-build-failing-after-update-to-android-studio-2-3-canary-3/41149031). might be helpful

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason behind taking too much time on `refreshing gradle project` is, it was downloading gradle distribution and each time and for some network issue the download was never being completed. The `zip` file for gradle distribution was `91MB`. So the network error + slow internet connection made it impossible task for my Android Studio. 
I found two solution for this:

First approach is we have to download the gradle distribution manually from [services.gradle.org/distributions](https://services.gradle.org/distributions). Then follow the process of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20315737/1113211) of the question - [Android Studio Stuck at Gradle Download on create new project.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16580873)

Second approach is somewhat like the first approach but less complex. Download gradle distribution. Extract it somewhere. Then go to:

**File > Settings > Build, Execution and Deployment > Gradle**

Check `Use local gradle distribution`. Set the `Gradle home` to the folder we have extracted.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem

What I have done is

> 1.Close your project
>
> 2.Delete folders of `.idea` , `.gradle`, `gradle` folders from **my project**(not from home). then
>
> 3.File=>open your project

press `ok` in the dialogue box it will automatically set the gradle for you.
or

You can specify **gradle path**

> settings->build excecution deployment->build tools->gradle set your
>   gradle home path to your downloaded gradle

Comment: I have gone through these steps several times and also tried some other ways. I actually where it gets stuck while `refreshing project`.

Comment: Yes. Removed the `gradle` directory from project, remove `.gradle` from home.

Comment: @salmanwahed please remove `.gradle` file from your project also

Comment: Have tried these actually with no luck. Can you tell me the reason why should I delete all these?

Comment: because the gradle distribution is changed. And if you manually set this . Error may occur

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137208/discussion-between-kiran-benny-joseph-and-salman-wahed).

Comment: Downloading gradle manually and using the local gradle distribution solved this issue for now. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this case because of slow internet, Each time while beginning with the project, it downloads the gradles taking more time.Finally refreshing complete after waiting for 10 minute.

Comment: The download itself was complete in about 15 seconds (100 MBit) but IntelliJ was still stuck at the download task.